# Directus - Installing the exact version still installs the latest version

Tags: package.json, directus

I am trying to replicate the cloud server's Directus version, which is `9.0.0-rc.53`, on my local machine. I've followed the standard procedure of creating the project a using the following command:

`npx create-directus-project project-name`

I followed the approach from the [Directus Docs](https://docs.directus.io/guides/projects/) to downgrade the server doing the following command:

`npm install directus@9.0.0-rc.53`

However, after doing so, the Directus server still remains the on the latest version, `9.0.0-rc.75`. I've tried doing the following:

1. Removing the caret in `package.json` (Changing `^9.0.0-rc.53` to `9.0.0-rc.53`)
2. Removing the caret from all Directus-related dependencies in `package-lock.json`
3. Deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again after doing 1 and 2.

Despite this, I see that the Directus-related packages being used in the `node_modules` folder is still the latest version, `9.0.0-rc.75`.

The reason why I need this specific version is that there is a breaking change in `GraphQL` specifically where the `GraphQL schema` is different from these two versions.

Upgrading the Cloud's server is currently not an option as `GraphQL` queries that are in place will no longer work.

How am I to go about installing a specific version of Directus?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The tag in GitHub repository is v9.0.0-rc.53. So try to install as

```
npm install directus@v9.0.0-rc.53
```

This worked for me. For some reason npm may not be recognizing you put the wrong version, so it installs the last one.